# Custom-collapsing template parameter space

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way to define a type `Box<T>` to mean `Box<T,T>` (for various types `T`) if `Box<Tx,Ty>` is already a defined type (for various types `Tx`, `Ty`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the second template parameter for `Box` a default argument:

```
template <typename T, typename U=T>
class Box {
};
```

Now you can write `Box<T>` for `Box<T,T>`, but you can still choose to write `Box<T,U>` if the types are different.